# Internal working of AMQP protocol

Tags: amazon-web-services, amqp, spring-amqp, cloudamqp

I have a doubt - that which data structure does AMQP internally uses for storing messages.
I know it has
Transport (TCP/IP)
Messaging Protocol & Type System

Portable Representation of Message Properties
Message Broker – the MOM Layer
API Mappings
Routing between Brokers 
Management –in a forthcoming addition
The AMQP Network Protocol

I believe it should be queue only .

If so then all the operations like blocking the queue and making it durable (etc) are performed on it ?
Any example of how it works (url or blogs will work)

Does AWS SQS follows AMQP architecture only?

Comment: Yes I got the answer it internally uses queue only and all the operations are performed on it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMQP standard (or better to say standards, since 0.9.x and 1.x are quite different) does not state, or prescribe how are messages to be stored. And in fact different implementations choose different ways of storing them.

Regarding AWS SQS I am not aware that it follows AMQP architecture.